# Android studio v0.3.2, gradle, google maps v2.0 Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-android-api-2

I have problem with Google Maps Android v2.0. Because i try a lot of options and I always get this stacktrace:

```
 1-03 17:39:26.015    2398-2398/com.** E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.**/com.**
.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:208)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:111)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
            at com.**.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:409)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:377)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:277)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:208)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:111)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
            at com.**.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" on path: /data/app/com.**-2.apk
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:399)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:377)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:277)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:208)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:111)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
            at com.**.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My build.grade:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36'
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+' //3.2.25
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.+'
}
```

My manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="*****"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.*.NonLoggedActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.*.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible" >

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.*.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<permission
    android:name="com.*.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.*.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
<uses-library
    android:name="com.google.android.maps"
    android:required="false" />
```

In activity_main.xml:

```
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Sdk manager:
[image]

And Project structure:
[image]

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: What device are you trying to run on?

Comment: Simulator and http://www.goclever.com/de/produkte,c1/tablet-pc,c5/aries-785,a149.html

Comment: What versions of Android are there?

Comment: Do you have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Looks like google-play-services.jar classes are not put in your apk, but your build.gradle is correct. Do you install it on device using `gradle installDebug`?

Comment: I tryied gradle installDebug and i got: :*:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices3136Library UP-TO-DATE

Comment: When I install with installDebug, I still have this error:      Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.*-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.*-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can resolve this problem when you change dependencies to:

```
    dependencies {
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.25' //3.2.25
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.+'
}
```

and write this in command line

```
sudo . gradlew clean
sudo . gradlew build
sudo . gradlew installDebug
```

I tried this in Android Studio, but when I did it via console my application run successfull.

Answer (score 2):

Other solution:

Rebuild project in android studio:

```
Build->rebuild project
```

Answer (score 0):

A problem is that you miss this:

```
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

So, any solution will not succed, because masked by this other problem.